# PHP Query Inserting Apostrophe in database

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I just want to ask if there's any possible way to insert values in the database that has an apostrophe?

Comment: Read http://bobby-tables.com, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You just need to escape it appropriately in your query. Use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068), they will take care of that for you.